# Python Create vertical Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have created a code in which from my lists I create an array, which must be vertical, like a vector, the problem is that using the reshape method I don't get anything.

```
import numpy as np

data = [[ 28,    29,    30,    19,    20,    21],
        [ 31,    32,    33,    22,    23,      24],
        [  1,    34,    35,    36,    25,    26],
        [  2,    19,    20,    21,    10,    11],
        [  3,     4,     5,     6,     7,    8 ]]

index = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    index.append([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2],
                    data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5]])   
    y = np.array([index[i]])
#    y.reshape(6,1)
```

Is there any solution for these cases? Thank you.

I'm looking for something like this to remain:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view each row as a column, transpose the array in any one of the following ways:

```
index = data.T
index = np.transpose(data)
index = data.transpose()
index = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1)
index = np.moveaxis(data, 1, 0)
...
```

Each column of `index` will be a row of `data`. If you just want to access one column at a time, you can do that too. For example, to get row 3 (4th row) of the original array, any of the following would work:

```
y = data[3, :]
y = data[3]
y = index[:, 3]
```

You can get a column vector from the result by explicitly reshaping it to one:

```
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))
y = np.expand_dims(y, 1)
```

Remember that reshaping creates a new array object which views the same data as the original. The only way I know to reshape an array in-place is to assign to its `shape` attribute:

```
y.shape = (y.size, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten()` from numpy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

(if you want a copy of the original array without modifying the original)

```
import numpy as np

data = [[ 28,    29,    30,    19,    20,    21],
        [ 31,    32,    33,    22,    23,      24],
        [  1,    34,    35,    36,    25,    26],
        [  2,    19,    20,    21,    10,    11],
        [  3,     4,     5,     6,     7,    8 ]]

data = np.array(data).flatten()

print(data.shape)
```

```
(30,)
```

You can also use `ravel()`

(if you don't want a copy)

`data = np.array(data).ravel()`

If your array always has 2-d, this also works,

`data = data.reshape(-1)`

Comment: Use `ravel` to avoid copying the data